# Passing and returning a string pointer in a function

Tags: c

I am new to the concept of character pointers and strings.So, having trouble in passing a string pointer and returning a string pointer in a function.the function is "remove".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* remove(char* ,char ,int );
int main(){
    int count, i;
    char ch;
    char* a;
    char* b;
    b=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    a=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    gets(a);
    for(i=0;*a='\0';i++)
    {
        ch=a[i];
        b=remove(&a[i],ch,i);
    }
}

char* remove(char* str,char x,int k)
{
    char* str2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);

    int i,j;
    j=0;
    int len;
    len=strlen(str);
    for(i=k;i<len;k++)
    {
        if(str[i]!='x')
        {
            str2[j]=str[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return str2;
}
```

The errors which i am getting are

```
error:conflicting types for 'remove'
```

In the line where the function was declared and defined in the subsequent line.

Comment: Doesn't the rest of the error say: `/usr/include/stdio.h:178:12: note: previous declaration of ‘remove’ was here`?

Comment: It's not the 1970s any more.  You can write `a = malloc(10)` ; and the `gets` function no longer exists.

Comment: Your `remove` function fails to null terminate `str2`

Comment: `for(i=k;i<len;k++)` Are you sure that you want to increment `k` ?

Comment: oh yea, it was a silly mistake.Got it!

Comment: Well the `gets` work on my version of code block!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `remove()` is already defined in `stdio.h`.

```
int remove(const char *pathname);
```

Please give some other name to your function `char* remove()`.

Note : Whenever you get such error, please try to look at manual page. If you are in unix. Simply type `man func_name` in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`remove()` is a standard function. You need to choose a different name for your `remove()` function name. Because your function definition for `remove()` differs with the prototype found in `stdio.h`.